# Azure to Azure Site Recovery issue (ARM)

Tags: azure

I'm trying to setup Azure to Azure Site Recovery but getting an following error while replicating (Enabling Protection).

Error:

Error ID78007
Error MessageThe requested operation did not complete.
Provider errorProvider error code: 31332

Provider error message:

```
The virtual machine information could not be retrieved.
```

Provider error possible causes:

```
  1. The agent on the source server is not responding or could not connect to the configuration server.
  2. A different version of mobility service is installed on source machine.
  3. Mobility service agent is registered to a different configuration server.
  4. Configuration server passphrase may have changed.
```

Provider error recommended action:

```
  1. Uninstall the older version of mobility service (Microsoft Azure Site Recovery Mobility Service/Master Target Server) manually.
  2. Restart the job and if the issue persists, contact Microsoft support.
```

Possible causes: Check the provider error for more details.

Recommendation: Resolve the issue as recommended in the provider error details.

Kindly help.

Comment: well, did you go through the recommended steps?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to associate my Azure Machine with Recovery Services vault it just getting an error while Enabling Replication.

Answer (score 1):

I did run into the same issue and even had to raise an MS support ticket. 
However, I was able to fix it myself. You have to restart your Virtual Machine for the Mobility agent to start responding and communicating with your Recovery Vault. If the restart still does not fix it then uninstall the mobility agent from the machine, unprotect the machine and then reprotect again.

Let us know if this fixed your issue!

Thanks